# Chrome is using over 100% CPU

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, ssd, performance, disk-usage

My Google Chrome is behaving very erratically. I saw that Chrome was using over 100% CPU, so I opened Chrome's built-in task manager, which shows me that the task "browser" is using over 100%, and also the task for this Stack Exchange tab. It is jumping back and forth between these crazy values and very low ones (~1% level).

I have also been noticing that my computer has been lagging in general, sporadically. Usually it's fine, but then it will seize up and for 5 minutes or so I can hardly move windows or switch desktops without unbearable lag.

How do I go about diagnosing such a vague issue as this?

Specs:

- 4x Intel i5-6200U (2.3GHz)
- 8GB RAM
- Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

It also probably doesn't help that my disk (256GB SSD) is 95% full, but still this behavior seems strange.

Comment: If your CPU has 4 cores, and Chrome is using around 100% sometimes, that is only one of the 4 cores. This is quite normal, especially when initially loading pages, particularly with lots of JavaScript in them. It's also common when streaming videos and such. The lag you speak is more likely related to your disk being nearly full, and something causing extremely heavy I/O usage.

Comment: IOW, try clearing the cache in Chrome, and reducing the amount of cache it can have, and see if it helps any.

Comment: Try disabling any unnecessary add-ons and extensions

Comment: Is it 61? Try to `chrome://flags/#enable-color-correct-rendering`

Comment: @Redbob more info?

Comment: You could type this command at Chrome address bar, to enable color rendering. Maybe solves CPU struggle.

Comment: @Redbob I understand that, but why should enabling color rendering help this issue?

Comment: Just a suggestion. As Chrome 61 has any issues and several people claims about its performance, in special, color rendering , this feature may be influencing on it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the SSD model you need to leave 20% free space on the SSD for best performance, although some SSDs continue to function normally even when they are 95% full. Try freeing up space on the SSD by copying some of the files from the SSD to another disk and deleting those files from the SSD. The second disk could be another internal hard drive or an external hard drive.